# How to graph $f(x)=(1-\cos(2x-2))/(x-1)^2$ analytically?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, rational-functions

I am asked to graph the function

$$f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x-2)}{(x-1)^2}$$

I only have an issue when it comes to determining the hole at $x=1$ analytically. Graphing the function on a graphing utility reveals a hole at $x=1$ rather than a vertical asymptote. I know that by simply plugging in the value $1$ for $x$, one will see that both the numerator and denominator equate to zero. This shows that there is at least one factor of $(x-1)$ that can be extracted from the numerator.

I would like to know how to simplify this function analytically in such a way that two factors of $(x-1)$ can be obtained from the numerator. I believe one must make use of an inverse function down the line in order to extract the obvious $(x-1)$ hiding in the $\cos(2x-2)=\cos(2(x-1))$ term. That is as far as I got in the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   look at $\,f(x+1)=\dfrac{1- \cos 2x}{x^2} = \dfrac{2 \sin^2 x}{x^2}\,$, then shift the origin back.

Comment: That's actually really cool. I always thought that you absolutely needed the same term in the numerator and denominator in order to confirm the existence of holes. Your suggestion shows that two terms in both the top and bottom of the fraction equal zero for the same x. Hence, we know a hole exists at that value of x even though nothing is explicitly cancelled. Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.